# Getting last position of an element

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm programming a Snake game in C# (Win Form). The snake should become longer if it eats one block of food.

```
if(d.eaten  == true) // embedded in a timer_tick event

    {
        PictureBox a = new PictureBox();

        a.Top = panel1.Controls[2].Top;
        a.Left = panel1.Controls[2].Left;
        a.BackColor = Color.Black;
        panel1.Controls.Add(a);
        a.Width = 10;
        a.Height = 10; 

    }

    for (int i = 3; i < panel1.Controls.Count; i++) // i = 3 because we already have 3 controls in panel1
    {
        panel1.Controls[i].Top  = panel1.Controls[i-1].Top;
        panel1.Controls[i].Left = panel1.Controls[i-1].Left;
    }
```

This code will create new pictureboxes but all these pictureboxes get the position of the snake - they will overlap. If I add some fix values to the position like `panel1.Controls[i].Top = panel1.Controls[i-1].Top -10;`, then the body of the snake won't move correctly.

I think I need a way to find the last position of an element - not the current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a snake game, the snake grows on the next move, not immediately. This is the trick that solves your problem. So simply remember that it needs to grow and add a new segment during the next move when you actually know the new position.

A snake game also uses a queue for the snake itself. You pop a segment from the back, and push it on the front with a new position.